# How can I re-install wine or make it work?

Tags: opensuse, wine

I've freshly installed OpenSUSE 12.1 64 bit on my box but Wine doesn't start. Winecfg doesn't start either. I've tried to start wine from the menu and from the terminal to no avail. I've tried zypper in wine but it won't let me replace my current wine installation. My current wine version is wine-1.3.30. I've installed opensuse from DVD. How can I re-install wine or make it work? As requested:

```
wine64 notepad.exe
wine: created the configuration directory '/root/.wine'
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x61e45620 1 61e40000: stub
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x61780ba0 1 61700000: stub
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x64f69540 1 64f40000: stub
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x622c6620 1 622c0000: stub
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x6ce47620 1 6ce40000: stub
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x254b20 1 240000: stub
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x67112de0 1 67040000: stub
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x6f7e6ea0 1 6f7c0000: stub
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x3ab6a0 1 390000: stub
fixme:seh:RtlAddFunctionTable 0x6b35e700 1 69c40000: stub
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0xdae308, overlapped 0xdae2d0): stub
wine: configuration in '/root/.wine' has been updated.
```

It opens notepad! What happens?

But wine notepad.exe doesn't work. What does this means?

```
winetricks d3dx9_42 vcrun2008 xact
```

give this

```
wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string
```

and winecfg doesn't start? It this a 32-bit issue? I've installed a 64 bit OS?

Comment: Can you post any errors you get if you do a `wine notepad.exe` from a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like there is also wine 32 bit installed with the normal 64 bit install. I've backup and rename wine and softlink wine 64. Now it seems to work!

```
mv wine wine32
ln -sf wine64 wine
```

But it doesn't work either. Maybe I forgot to enable 32-bit emulation:

```
zcat /proc/config.gz | grep IA32_EMULATION
CONFIG_IA32_EMULATION=y
```

This can help:

```
rm ~/.wine
export WINEARCH=win32
```

and delete the softlink wine64. It seems to me wine64 isn't working. But now it gives me this error when I want to start a program:

```
err:virtual:map_file_into_view failed to set 00000007 protection on file map, noexec filesystem
```

I've not mounted any filesystem noexec? The problem is that each stub must be installed in wine. I cannot start stubs from my existing Windows partition.